# Fix broken links on shared library g++

Tags: g++, shared, dynamic-linking

I have an executable which links to opencv 2.2. However, I have removed opencv 2.2 and I have opencv 2.3 installed.

The question is, is there a way to link this executable to the new shared library without recompiling the whole source code? How can I fix those broken links?

```
running ldd:

    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff17fff000)
    libSM.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libSM.so.6 (0x00007fd6f0e0d000)
    libICE.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libICE.so.6 (0x00007fd6f0bf2000)
    libXmu.so.6 => /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6 (0x00007fd6f09d8000)
    libXi.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libXi.so.6 (0x00007fd6f07c8000)
    libGLU.so.1 => /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1 (0x00007fd6f0559000)
    libGL.so.1 => /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1 (0x00007fd6f0353000)
    libopencv_core.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_imgproc.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_highgui.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_ml.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_video.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_features2d.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_calib3d.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_objdetect.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_contrib.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_legacy.so.2.2 => not found
    libopencv_flann.so.2.2 => not found
    libglut.so.3 => /usr/lib/libglut.so.3 (0x00007fd6f0109000)
```

...

thanks guys,

Samuel

Comment: Is `2.3` binary compatible with `2.2`? If the ABI did not change, I think you can work around the problem with symlinks.

Comment: I have tried to create symbolic links for that, but it did not work

Comment: Does `ldd` still say `not found`? Does your program crash or fail to load?

Comment: Glad to hear that :) Should I post this as an answer so you can accept it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If OpenCV version 2.3 is *binary compatible* with version 2.2, i.e. if the [ABI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) did not undergo breaking changes, you can work around the problem with [symbolic links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link):

```
# ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.3 /usr/lib/libopencv_core.so.2.2
# ln -s /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.3 /usr/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so.2.2
.
.
.
```